# Query item in nested array

Tags: mongodb-query

Customer appointments with top level `locationId` sample data set:

```
[
    {
        "locationId": 9999,
        "customerAppointments": [
            {
                "customerId": "1",
                "appointments": [
                    {
                        "appointmentId": "cbbce566-da59-42c2-8845-53976ba63d56",
                        "locationName": "Sullivan St"
                    },
                    {
                        "appointmentId": "5f09e2af-ddae-47aa-9f7c-fd1001a9c5e6",
                        "locationName": "Oak St"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "customerId": "2",
                "appointments": [
                    {
                        "appointmentId": "964a3c1c-ccec-4082-99e2-65795352ba79",
                        "locationName": "Kellet St"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "customerId": "3",
                "appointments": []
            }
        ]
    },
  {
   ...
  },
  {
   ...
  }
]
```

I need to pull out appointment by `locationId` and `customerId` and only get the appointment for that customerId e.g

Sample response:

```
[
    {
        "appointmentId": "964a3c1c-ccec-4082-99e2-65795352ba79",
        "locationName": "Kellet St"
    }
]
```

Tried below query, but it just returns all records for all customers ids (which is kind of expected):

```
db.getCollection("appointments").find(
    {
        "locationId" : NumberInt(9999),
        "customerAppointments" : {
            "$elemMatch" : {
                "customerId" : "2"
            }
        }
    }
);
```

But how can I get just the appointment record for a specific `customerId`?

Comment: You are looking for something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KOjFOTKzMQb)? A customer can have more than one appointment records. You want to get all?

Comment: ... or like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4YfN8AQwD1F)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - they work well, however my employer is using an older version of MongoDB that does not support the `$getField` operator (new in version 5).

So I came up with this:

```
db.getCollection("appointments").aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "locationId": NumberInt(9999)
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$customerAppointments"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "customerAppointments.customerId": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      appointments: "$customerAppointments.appointments"
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Sorry for the formatting - stackoverflow comment field is crappy.

Answer (score 0):

When asking this question I was unaware of the older version of MongoDB driver (< v5) so we cannot use the `$getField` operator.

However, this query seems to work well:

```
db.getCollection("appointments").aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "locationId": NumberInt(9999)
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$customerAppointments"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "customerAppointments.customerId": "2"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      appointments: "$customerAppointments.appointments"
    }
  }
]);
```

Yields:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63eebe95c7a0da54804c1db2"),
    "appointments" : [
        {
            "appointmentId" : "964a3c1c-ccec-4082-99e2-65795352ba79",
            "locationName" : "Kellet St"
        }
    ]
}
```